# I can ping IP address but can not ping hostname

Tags: ip, ping, hostname

My address:

```
user@pc1:~$ ifconfig eth0 |grep "inet " 
        inet addr:192.168.2.10  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
```

I can ping this address

```
user@pc1:~$ ping -c 1 192.168.2.11
PING 192.168.2.11 (192.168.2.11) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.2.11: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.686 ms

--- 192.168.2.11 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.686/0.686/0.686/0.000 ms
```

But pinging its hostname seems to resolve the IP address, but it doesn’t return pings.

```
user@pc1:~$ ping -c 1 pc2.dtvg.nix 
PING pc2.dtvg.nix (192.128.2.11) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- pc2.dtvg.nix ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

While pinging another hostname on the same network works fine.

```
user@pc1 ~$ ping -c1 gw.dtvg.nix 
PING gw.dtvg.nix (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from gw.dtvg.nix (192.168.2.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.220 ms

--- gw.dtvg.nix ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.220/0.220/0.220/0.000 ms
```

My /etc/resolve.conf

```
user@pc1:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 127.0.0.1
search dtvg.nix
```

named.conf on my nameserver (gw)

```
root@gw:/var/cache/bind# cat /etc/bind/named.conf.local  
zone "dtvg.nix" {
    type master;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.dtvg.nix";
    allow-update { key dhcpupdate; };   
};

zone "2.168.192.in-addr.arpa" {
    type master;
    notify no;
    file "/var/cache/bind/db.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa";
allow-update { key dhcpupdate; };
};
```

Reverse lookup on my nameserver, gw, with unnecessary hosts removed

```
root@gw:/var/cache/bind# cat db.2.168.192.in-addr.arpa 
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
2.168.192.in-addr.arpa   IN SOA dtvg.nix. root.dtvg.nix. (
    140        ; serial
    604800     ; refresh (1 week)
    86400      ; retry (1 day)
    2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
    604800     ; minimum (1 week)
)
    NS   gw.dtvg.nix.
$ORIGIN 2.168.192.in-addr.arpa.
1           PTR  gw.dtvg.nix.
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
10           PTR    pc1
11           PTR    pc2
```

Forward lookup zone file on my nameserver, gw, with unnecessary hosts removed

```
root@phoenix:/var/cache/bind# cat db.dtvg.nix 
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
dtvg.nix        IN SOA  dtvg.nix. root.dtvg.nix. (
    140        ; serial
    604800     ; refresh (1 week)
    86400      ; retry (1 day)
    2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
    604801     ; minimum (1 week 1 second)
)
    NS  gw.dtvg.nix
$ORIGIN dtvg.nix.
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
gw      A   192.168.2.1
pc1     A   192.128.2.10
pc2     A   192.128.2.11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the zone file you have a different IP address for `pc2.dtvg.nix`: `192.128.2.11` than you were successfully pinging: `192.168.2.11`.

You confirmed that the IP addresses in the zone file `/var/cache/bind/db.dtvg.nix` are wrong so please correct them:

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
dtvg.nix        IN SOA  dtvg.nix. root.dtvg.nix. (
    140        ; serial
    604800     ; refresh (1 week)
    86400      ; retry (1 day)
    2419200    ; expire (4 weeks)
    604801     ; minimum (1 week 1 second)
)
    NS  gw.dtvg.nix
$ORIGIN dtvg.nix.
$TTL 604800 ; 1 week
gw      A   192.168.2.1
pc1     A   192.168.2.10
pc2     A   192.168.2.11
```

Comment: On my network gw has address 192.168.2.1 pc1 has address 192.168.2.10 and pc2 has address 192.168.2.11 . When i am on pc1 (192.168.2.10) and ping 192.168.2.11, I get ping replies, but when I ping pc2.dtvg.nix it resolves it to IP address 192.168.2.11 but doesn’t return any pings.

Comment: @KeithReynolds: In the question the ping makes to resolve the name to a different IP address: `192.128.2.11`

Comment: @KeithReynolds: `pc2.dtvg.nix` resolves to 192. **128** .2.11. Do you see the difference from the address of the machine? 192. **168** .2.11

Comment: That was it. I over looked the address as you said. I didn't catch it at first but you answered it.

Comment: @KeithReynolds: I know this overlooking of a small typo even when you are looking at it again and again :)